# Remove specific characters from a String using an extension

Tags: swift, string

I’ve found this awesome extension that remove everything except the characters in the quotation marks.

```
extension String.UnicodeScalarView {
    var removeCharacters: String {
        return String(filter(("cfh".unicodeScalars).contains))
    }
}

print("abcd123efg".unicodeScalars.removeCharacters) // it prints “cf”, my desirable result is to make it print  “abd123eg”
```

It prints “cf”, my desirable result is to make it print  “abd123eg”.
Can you help me invert it to remove only the characters that are between the quotation marks and leave everything else?

Note:It is also important that it recognize (unicodeScalars) so please don’t remove this part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to negate the call to `contains`:

```
return String(filter { !"cfh".unicodeScalars.contains($0) })
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking [@rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) into consideration, if you are using `extension` then make sure you think about generics and work in any case. Like you have kept "cfh" as a static `String`, what if you want to remove "abc", then it won't work. So, here is the modified version:

```
extension String.UnicodeScalarView {
    func removeCharacters(_ characters: String) -> String {
        return String(filter { !characters.unicodeScalars.contains($0) })
    }
}
```

**Usage:** `"abcd123efg".unicodeScalars.removeCharacters("cfh")`

Comment: This is really useful! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension for String like below

```
extension String {

func removeGroupOfCharacters(removalString : String) -> String {

    // return an Array without the removal Characters
    let filteredCharacters = Array(self).filter { !Array(removalString).contains($0) }

    // build a String with the filtered Array
    let filtered = String(filteredCharacters)

    return filtered
}
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let unfiltered = "abcd123efg"

    let removal = "cfh"

    print(unfiltered.removeGroupOfCharacters(removalString: removal)) 

   // => output will be like this "abd123eg\n"


}
```

Comment: Why would you make this an extension to `UIViewController`? It's a string function, not a view controller function.

Comment: The *triple conversion* is not very efficient.

Answer (score -1):

It's a basic example. You can do like that.

```
extension String {
    return aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "X", with: "")
}
```